# Each node has a score (percentage) which is updated weekly & want to show latest and the past scores in below/in a chart

Tags: nodes, charts

The site is keeping scores (by percentage) of how well it does in a certain area. So each node is a different area and that node will have a score of 7% in week 1. An example: Liverpool's score is 11.23% for week 1 of 2018, week 2 that node (Liverpool) is updated and it gets a score of 12.01%, etc, etc.

In week 2, we update that nodes score to 9.5%, I want to show this prominently at the top of the page as the current score. Then underneath, show a chart of the previous scores or at least at the very minimum show all the scores in a neat line, going back/down in order of date.

I then also want to show all of these nodes (areas) in one view, showing in a ranking list, this would just be a view?

Is this the right way to go about it, with nodes that are updated/revisions? Or am I thinking about this all wrong?

What about using table field for the past scores and just having the current score as it's own field shown at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement them with a [field_collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) (currently not stable for either D7 or D8) or with the [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module (currently stable for D8 only) if you need to keep track of old scores of each node and when they've been set.

I've also implemented similar things (paired values) by simply having two multivalue fields, one after the other, and letting editors keep them in sync manually, then rendering them together in a table or the alike with a custom template.

Using two simple multivalue fields (and they could be both numeric fields, if the time is something simple as the number of the week) may eventually simplify accessing such data in a view.

Comment: I ended up using Paragraphs for all the old scores and this made them all fit next to each other which was perfect.